# Python script to modify the XML file

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I have an XML file with following contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Configuration xmlns="....">
    <Name>Order Entry</Name>
    <Comment>Simple Order Entry </Comment>
    <Connection>
        <UserName>myuser</UserName>
        <Password>myuser</Password>
        <ConnectString>some_string</ConnectString>
        <DriverType>jdbc Driver</DriverType>
    </Connection>
    <Load>
        <EnvironmentVariables>
            <Variable Key="CAT_URL">SOME_URL</Variable>
            <Variable Key="CAT_USERNAME">myuser</Variable>
            <Variable Key="CAT_PASSWORD">myuser</Variable>
        </EnvironmentVariables>
    </Load>
</Configuration>
```

I want to modify the XML file to look like this.
Basically i need to modify value of

```
> <ConnectString>some_string</ConnectString>

to 

> <ConnectString>my_string</ConnectString>


and 

> <Variable Key="CAT_URL">SOME_URL</Variable>
> 
to

> <Variable Key="CAT_URL">MY_URL</Variable>
```

So end XML file should look something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Configuration xmlns="....">
    <Name>Order Entry</Name>
    <Comment>Simple Order Entry </Comment>
    <Connection>
        <UserName>myuser</UserName>
        <Password>myuser</Password>
        <ConnectString>my_string</ConnectString>
        <DriverType>jdbc Driver</DriverType>
    </Connection>
    <Load>
        <EnvironmentVariables>
            <Variable Key="CAT_URL">MY_URL</Variable>
            <Variable Key="CAT_USERNAME">myuser</Variable>
            <Variable Key="CAT_PASSWORD">myuser</Variable>
        </EnvironmentVariables>
    </Load>
</Configuration>
```

Need a python script which can help me with this.

Tried this.

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    mytree = ET.parse('my_file.xml')
    myroot = mytree.getroot()
    for url in myroot.iter('CAT_URL'):
         url.text('MY_URL')
    for connect_str in myroot.iter('ConnectString'):
         connect_str.text('my_string')
```

Doesnt work

Comment: Modified the XML file.

Comment: Your xml have a namespace, therefore the tag name looks like in this format `{your_namespace}tagname `.

Answer (score 1):

In your example the namespace definition is missing, therefore I replace it with HUGO placeholder. You can search with the `find()` function of `xml.etree.ElementTree`. You have to `register_namespace` the namespace, once.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Configuration xmlns="HUGO">
    <Name>Order Entry</Name>
    <Comment>Simple Order Entry </Comment>
    <Connection>
        <UserName>myuser</UserName>
        <Password>myuser</Password>
        <ConnectString>some_string</ConnectString>
        <DriverType>jdbc Driver</DriverType>
    </Connection>
    <Load>
        <EnvironmentVariables>
            <Variable Key="CAT_URL">SOME_URL</Variable>
            <Variable Key="CAT_USERNAME">myuser</Variable>
            <Variable Key="CAT_PASSWORD">myuser</Variable>
        </EnvironmentVariables>
    </Load>
</Configuration>"""


tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
ns = {'xlmns': 'HUGO'} # replace HUGO with the right namespace url
ET.register_namespace('',"HUGO")

conString = tree.find(".//{*}ConnectString")
conString.text = 'my_string'

catUrl = tree.find('.//{*}Variable[@Key="CAT_URL"]')
catUrl.text = 'MY_URL'

ET.dump(tree)
```

Output:

```xml
<Configuration xmlns="HUGO">
    <Name>Order Entry</Name>
    <Comment>Simple Order Entry </Comment>
    <Connection>
        <UserName>myuser</UserName>
        <Password>myuser</Password>
        <ConnectString>my_string</ConnectString>
        <DriverType>jdbc Driver</DriverType>
    </Connection>
    <Load>
        <EnvironmentVariables>
            <Variable Key="CAT_URL">MY_URL</Variable>
            <Variable Key="CAT_USERNAME">myuser</Variable>
            <Variable Key="CAT_PASSWORD">myuser</Variable>
        </EnvironmentVariables>
    </Load>
</Configuration>
```

Option 2 with `iter()`:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from io import StringIO

xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Configuration xmlns="....">
    <Name>Order Entry</Name>
    <Comment>Simple Order Entry </Comment>
    <Connection>
        <UserName>myuser</UserName>
        <Password>myuser</Password>
        <ConnectString>some_string</ConnectString>
        <DriverType>jdbc Driver</DriverType>
    </Connection>
    <Load>
        <EnvironmentVariables>
            <Variable Key="CAT_URL">SOME_URL</Variable>
            <Variable Key="CAT_USERNAME">myuser</Variable>
            <Variable Key="CAT_PASSWORD">myuser</Variable>
        </EnvironmentVariables>
    </Load>
</Configuration>"""

my_file_xml = StringIO(xml)

mytree = ET.parse(my_file_xml)
myroot = mytree.getroot()
ET.register_namespace('',"....")

for elem in myroot.iter():
    # print(elem.tag, elem.text)
    if elem.tag == "{....}ConnectString":
        elem.text = "my_string"
    if elem.attrib == {"Key":"CAT_URL"}:
        elem.text = "MY_URL"
    
ET.dump(mytree)

tree1 = ET.ElementTree(myroot)
ET.indent(tree1, space= '  ')
tree1.write('modified.xml', encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.  Since you have provided xmlns="...." in '', elements.tag have values like "{....}ConnectString" , "{....}Variable" etc.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

my_string ="my_string"
my_url = "MY_URL"

tree = ET.parse('my_file.xml')

for elem in tree.iter():
    if elem.tag == "{....}ConnectString":        
        elem.text = my_string
    if elem.tag == "{....}Variable" and elem.get("Key") == "CAT_URL":
        elem.text = my_url        

with open('changed.xml', 'wb') as f:
    tree.write(f)      
    print("new file saved to changed.xml")
```

> output

```xml
<ns0:Configuration xmlns:ns0="....">
    <ns0:Name>Order Entry</ns0:Name>
    <ns0:Comment>Simple Order Entry </ns0:Comment>
    <ns0:Connection>
        <ns0:UserName>myuser</ns0:UserName>
        <ns0:Password>myuser</ns0:Password>
        <ns0:ConnectString>my_string</ns0:ConnectString>
        <ns0:DriverType>jdbc Driver</ns0:DriverType>
    </ns0:Connection>
    <ns0:Load>
        <ns0:EnvironmentVariables>
            <ns0:Variable Key="CAT_URL">MY_URL</ns0:Variable>
            <ns0:Variable Key="CATALOGUE_USERNAME">myuser</ns0:Variable>
            <ns0:Variable Key="CATALOGUE_PASSWORD">myuser</ns0:Variable>
        </ns0:EnvironmentVariables>
    </ns0:Load>
</ns0:Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple but dirty way is to open XML file as a plain text and replace required strings:

```
with open('my_file.xml', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = f.read().replace('<ConnectString>some_string</ConnectString>', '<ConnectString>my_string</ConnectString>').replace('<Variable Key="CAT_URL">SOME_URL</Variable>', '<Variable Key="CAT_URL">MY_URL</Variable>')

with open('my_file.xml', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Configuration xmlns="....">
    <Name>Order Entry</Name>
    <Comment>Simple Order Entry </Comment>
    <Connection>
        <UserName>myuser</UserName>
        <Password>myuser</Password>
        <ConnectString>my_string</ConnectString>
        <DriverType>jdbc Driver</DriverType>
    </Connection>
    <Load>
        <EnvironmentVariables>
            <Variable Key="CAT_URL">MY_URL</Variable>
            <Variable Key="CAT_USERNAME">myuser</Variable>
            <Variable Key="CAT_PASSWORD">myuser</Variable>
        </EnvironmentVariables>
    </Load>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

here's my script. It's probably not perfect, but it works.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Load the XML file
tree = ET.parse('my_file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

# Define the key-value pairs you want to modify
array_key = [["CAT_URL", "MY_URL"],
             ["ConnectString", "my_string"]]

# Function to search for and modify elements
def search(search_key):
    for element in root.iter():
        if element.tag.endswith(search_key[0]):
            element.text = search_key[1]

# Iterate through the array_key and apply modifications
for i in range(len(array_key)):
    search(array_key[i])

# Write the modified XML to a new file
tree.write('modified_file.xml', encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```